# for each loop to add events to full calendar

Tags: php, jquery, html, web, fullcalendar

I'm using Full calendar jQuery component and I'm trying to add events too it by going through a loop of divs .. but it's not working ..

Here is the Javascript code .. **the commented line are the code the has the problem when added ..**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [
            //$("div.allEvents").each( function ( index ){      when I add this to the Jquery code .. it doesn't work
                {
                    //title: $(this).children('#event').val(),    replace this by the next line 
                    title: $('#event').val(),

                    //start: new Date( y, m, $(this).children('#date').val() )   replace this by the next line 
                    start: new Date( y, m, $('#date').val() )
                },
            //} );      End of each loop
        ]
    });

});
```

and Here is the CSS and HTML Code ..

```
<div class="allEvents">
<input type='hidden' id='event' value='Alaa' />
<input type='hidden' id='date' value='21' />
</div>
<div class="allEvents">
<input type='hidden' id='event' value='Waheeb' />
<input type='hidden' id='date' value='29' />
</div>
```

```
<style type='text/css'>

body {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

#calendar {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do the loop inside the `[...]`; instead, use a [function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) to initialize your events...

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="all-events">
  <div class="event">
    <input type="hidden" class="title" value="Alaa"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="date" value="12/21/2012" />    
  </div>
  ... rest of events go here
</div>
```

JavaScript

NOTE: you will need to wrap the date value into some type of converter to make it a Date type, I would recommend moment.js

```
var myEvents = [];

$.each( $( '.event' ), function( event ) {
  myEvents.push( {
    title : event.find( '.title' ).val(),
    start : event.find( '.date' ).val(),
    allDay : true
  } );  
} );

$myCal.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', myEvents );
```

Comment: That's another way. But in the code in question, Ghost just needs to change `events:[code]` to `events:function(st,en,cb) {var events[]; <<loop>> cb(events);}`